# Exporting relationships

Tags: relationships, export

I have an individual who receives from one to many honors. The honors are listed and an organization.  I created a relationship and have loaded the relationship. If I look at relationships in the contact record I am able to see them.

I want to export the relationships or at least the contact numbers so I can take them to another database and bring the records together. I am using a "Software as a Service", I don't have access to the database.

I tried this on 2 Civi systems one at 4.6.5 and the other one at 4.7.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried Reports > Contact Reports > Relationships? The contact IDs of both Contacts A and B are concatenated with the name in parenthesis, and you also have the option to add the contact ID for Contact A as a column as well as other fields you might need.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: I spent some frustrating time trying the search and export getting no wheres.  You gave me the solution Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Search and Export should work too. When you are in the export builder, if you go wwwwaaaayyyy down the bottom of the select list, you should find 'relationships' based options.